# Flutter Android notification that plays sound even if the phone is on silent mode using flutter_local_notifications package

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using *flutter_local_notifications* package for notifications in my Flutter Android app. The package version is the latest right now: 16.1.0.

I am scheduling a notification with custom sound, called *alarm* which is located /android/src/res/raw/ directory, to a certain DateTime and everything is working well. The notification already has the AllowWhileIdle behavior.

Now, I would like to implement the following behavior for the notification but I searched a lot and I can't figure it out: the phone screen should light up when the notification is received so you can better see the notification (as it happens when you receive a normal message in Android) and it should play the custom sound even if the phone is on silent mode.

I don't know if this is possible, especially to play the sound if the phone is on silent mode but I was seeing the possibility of using fullScreenIntent in Android within flutter_local_notifications package and maybe something like this could be done (I don't need a full screen popup, I mean if it can be used as a walkaround).

Here is my code:

```
static final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

static Future timerNotification({
    int id = 0,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    String? payload,
    required DateTime scheduledDate
}) async {
    return flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledDate, tz.local),
        await _notificationDetails(),
        payload: payload,
        androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime
    );
}

static Future _notificationDetails() async => const NotificationDetails(
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        "test_app", 
        "test_app",
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        enableVibration: true,
        playSound: true,
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("alarm")
    ),
    iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails()
);
```

I remark that this code is fully working for normal notification purpose, including the custom sound, I just need to add the described behavior.

Thank you very much for the help.